# How do I test private annotation aspect in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, annotations, aspect

**How do I test private annotation aspect in spring boot ?**

Example:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AspectClass {
    @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(CustomAnnotation)")
    private void privateMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) 
    {
       // Test this part
       System.out.println("Want to test this");
    }
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface  CustomAnnotation {
    String methodName() default "";
}
```

Expect to test the private method in Aspect with annotation trigger

Comment: You test it like you test any other private method: By making it package-private, and (optionally) annotating it with `@VisibleForTesting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is spring-boot-web then you can use your existing Application.java or you have to ceate a new ApplicationTest.java that atleast have the following

```java
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationTest {}
```

Sample Test:

```java
// AnnotationExecutor.java
@Component
public class AnnotationExecutor {

    @CustomAnnotation(methodName = "CustomAnnotation")
    public void someMethod(...) {
       // code
       ...
    }

}
```

```
// AnnotationTest.java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ComponentScan("com.your.package.path.*")
public class AnnotationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AnnotationExecutor annotationExecutor;

    @Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        annotationExecutor.someMethod(...);
        System.out.println("Test completed");
        // continue for assertion and testing ...
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Want to test this
Test completed
\\ ...
```